# Access denied for user'root'@'laptop-xxx'(using password:yes) when connect database mysql workbench with android studio. may i know what's the problem

Tags: mysql, android-studio

Access denied for user'root'@'laptop-xxx'(using password:yes)

link for the error --> https://ibb.co/3f3b5zh

Answer (score 0):

wrong password for 'root' user, please check the correct password again

Comment: ermm the password is the password that i set in mysql workbench right? if yes then my password is correct